# ZeroC Ice reference to class

Tags: java, slice, ice

I have the following two classes:

```
class RedirectInfo{


    ["java:getset"]string originalRetUrl;

    ["java:getset"]string proposalRetUrl;

    ["java:getset"]string comment;
};
```

and

```
class ResultTO extends ::http::ResponseTO {

    ["java:getset"]common::StringList pagingLinks;

    ["java:getset"]RedirectInfo ri;
};
```

When `RedirectInfo` is not null, I get the following exception:

> Exception is "ice.UnmarshalOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: Have you tried asking Zeroc support? I have found they are very responsive.